# How to run an executable file using Perl on Windows XP?

Tags: perl, executable

How to run an executable file using perl?

For instance, i want to run a plain notepad.exe. How could I achieve this?

This is what I've got:

```
my @args = system("notepad.exe");
system(@args) == 0  or die "system @args failed: $?";
```

But it returns:

`Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory blah blah blah.`

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, but what I found doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: `system` returns a single value, not an array. See `perldoc -f system` for a detailed description. [This thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=421595) on perlmonks discusses the error you're getting (with a few different solutions being presented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
my $prog = "C:\\strawberry\\perltest\\Extractor.bat";

if (-f $prog)   # does it exist?
{
    print "Will run notepad";
system($prog);
}
else  
{
    print "$prog doesn't exist.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. That's should explains. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems a bit confused. What you probably want is something like

```
my $cmd = "notepad.exe";
my @args = ($cmd, "readme.txt");

system(@args);

if($? == -1) {
    die "system @args failed: $?";
}
```

`system` returns a single value, not an array. See `perldoc -f system` for a detailed description.

[This thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=421595) on perlmonks discusses the error you're getting with a few different solutions being presented.

This answer is an extension of my original *comment*. Sorry if it's superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Perl internal error probably caused by a broken environment. Perl can't find the Windows shell `cmd.exe` that is used under the hood to run the program passed to `system`.

Use some utility as [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what's going on at the OS level.